# SafeMint in fullfillrandomness function [Chainlink]

Tags: erc-721, chainlink

It's not working

```
function mint() public payable {
        require(
            LINK.balanceOf(address(this)) >= fee,
            "Not enough LINK - fill contract with faucet"
        );
        requestRandomness(keyHash, fee);
 }
 function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 requestId, uint256 randomness) internal override {
      _safeMint(msg.sender, randomness);

 }
```

but it's working why?

```
function mint() public payable {
        require(
            LINK.balanceOf(address(this)) >= fee,
            "Not enough LINK - fill contract with faucet"
        );
        requestRandomness(keyHash, fee);
        requestToSender[requestId] = msg.sender;
    }
 function fulfillRandomness(bytes32 requestId, uint256 randomness) internal override {
      _safeMint(requestToSender[requestId], randomness);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a few assumptions about what you mean by "not working."

Based on the code, you have a significant difference in the address you are minting **to** in the `fulfillRandomness()` function.

In the first example, you use `msg.sender` to mint. This is within the `fulfillRandomness` function; the value of this address will most likely be the address of the `vrfCoordinator`. This would lead to the coordinator 'owning' the NFT that you just minted.

In the second example you are mapping the address that is requesting randomness to the request ID. `requestToSender[requestId] = msg.sender;` and then using that mapping again in the `fulfillRandomness()` function. `requestToSender[requestId]`. This will pass the requestor's address through to the `fulfillRandomness()` function, leading to the original requestor 'owning' the NFT.

If it is something else that is the issue, let me know.